# Is there a difference between hi and hi!, like hi Visual guibg=#FFEC8B and hi! Visual guibg=#FFEC8B

Tags: vim

This is a simple question, and I'm only asking it here because I couldn't find the answer in Vim's help, under `:h :hi`.
I have seen some people use `hi` and others use `hi!`, like `hi Visual guibg=#FFEC8B` vs `hi! Visual guibg=#FFEC8B` **OR** `hi link CursorLineNr Visual` vs `hi! link CursorLineNr Visual`. Is there a difference between them? From what I know, the bang `!` symbol toggles a setting. But when I run them, I get the same results, whether I use `hi` or `hi!`.

Comment: Have you read help carefully? Until `:h E414`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form `:hi! Group ctermbg=black`, the `!` nullifies the whole command, which makes it rather pointless.

In the form `:hi! link FromGroup ToGroup`, the `!` forces the link to be made even if `FromGroup` already has some attributes set.

See `:help :hi-link`.